# App crashing on network issue/server down

Tags: android, connection

I am using Asynctask to extract some data from the web and use it in further calculations. I have implemented a connectivity check as well, it returns false if there is no connection but It crashes if there is internet connection and "the server is down". I want to display a dialog to notify the user that their internet is experiencing problems. But I can't seem to get it right. Please help. Thanks in advance. :)

```
HttpClient client;
String URL, re, element;
JSONObject json, getjson;
int i, j, statusCode;
HttpGet httpget;
HttpResponse response;
HttpEntity entity;
InputStream is;
BufferedReader reader;
StringBuilder sb, sb1;

SharedPreferences getinput, passjson;
ProgressDialog pd;
Context context = DataRetrieve.this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.dataretrieve);
    // Bundle gotBasket = getIntent().getExtras();
    // URL = gotBasket.getString("key");
    getinput = getSharedPreferences("input", 0);
    URL = getinput.getString("key", null);

    if (!isNetworkReachable()) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle("No Network Connection");
        builder.setMessage("The Network is unavailable. Please check your internet connection.");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Settings",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent m = new Intent(
                                android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(m);
                    }
                });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent n = new Intent(DataRetrieve.this,
                                OpTilt.class);
                        startActivity(n);
                    }
                });

        builder.create().show();
    } else {
        Read r = new Read();
        r.execute();

    }

}

private boolean isNetworkReachable() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
ConnectivityManager mManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo current = mManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (current != null && current.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public class Read extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        pd = new ProgressDialog(DataRetrieve.this);
        pd.setTitle("Processing...");
        pd.setMessage("Please wait.");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.setIndeterminate(true);
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        re = null;
        is = null;
        json = null;
        try {

            httpget = new HttpGet(URL);
            client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            response = client.execute(httpget);
            entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
            statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            statusCode = -1;
            Log.e("log_tag", "Erro http " + e.toString());
        }
        if (statusCode == 200) {

            try {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,
                        "UTF-8"), 8);
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                re = sb.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Erro conversão " + e.toString());
            }

        }
        return re;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        pd.dismiss();
        try {

            json = new JSONObject(result);
            getjson = json.getJSONObject("Solar");
            String H[] = new String[getjson.length()];
            for (i = 0, j = 1; i < getjson.length(); i++, j++) {
                H[i] = getjson.getString("" + j);

            }
            SharedPreferences sendHm;
            sendHm = getSharedPreferences("parsedata", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sendHm.edit();
            for (int k = 0; k < H.length; k++) {
                editor.putString("Hm" + k, H[k]);
            }
            editor.commit();
            Intent f = new Intent(DataRetrieve.this, Calculator.class);
            startActivity(f);
            /*
             * Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); bundle.putStringArray("key1",
             * H); Intent f = new Intent(DataRetrieve.this,
             * Calculator.class); f.putExtras(bundle); startActivity(f);
             */

        }

        catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Erro dados " + e.toString());
        }

    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}

}
```

Comment: what`s wrong? do you get any errors? All the same the else-if branch in isNetworkReachable() is not necessary

Comment: You are right, I will remove it. The issue is that it only detects if network is enabled or not. I want to check if the network is even working or not. When the network goes down, the app shows a progress bar and then crashes.

Comment: I have edited the code and removed the else-if branch. But my issue remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your postExcute method code to below (you should check the result is not null or empty)

```
    pd.dismiss();
   if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(result))
    { 

    try {

        json = new JSONObject(result);
        getjson = json.getJSONObject("Solar");
        String H[] = new String[getjson.length()];
        for (i = 0, j = 1; i < getjson.length(); i++, j++) {
            H[i] = getjson.getString("" + j);

        }
        SharedPreferences sendHm;
        sendHm = getSharedPreferences("parsedata", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sendHm.edit();
        for (int k = 0; k < H.length; k++) {
            editor.putString("Hm" + k, H[k]);
        }
        editor.commit();
        Intent f = new Intent(DataRetrieve.this, Calculator.class);
        startActivity(f);
        /*
         * Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); bundle.putStringArray("key1",
         * H); Intent f = new Intent(DataRetrieve.this,
         * Calculator.class); f.putExtras(bundle); startActivity(f);
         */

    }

    catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Erro dados " + e.toString());
    }
  }
```

Comment: You Could First Ping Server for that  server is Down?

Comment: @Hardik.Thats great.It WORKS!..:D. Could you also explain what is this if statement doing? And one more thing. I have to put the notification dialog in the else statement now. Right?

Comment: TextUtils.isEmpty() checked the string is null or empty and you should put pd.dismiss() out of condition so i am edited my code see now.